# Mother in law is the daughter of mother in law

Tags: language, family

A **Male** and a **Female** were sitting on a bench in a garden. The **Gardener** asked the Male, "What is your relation with this Female?"
the **Male** replied, "***Her mother-in-law is the daughter of my mother-in-law.***"

What is the relation between them?

Comment: Is the gardener the female sitting on the bench in the garden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The female was

> the daughter in law of the male.

"Her mother-in-law is the daughter of my mother-in-law" can be simplified to

> "Her mother-in-law is my wife" 
> which implies that the female is his wife's daughter in law and also his daughter in law.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer:

> The phrase "the daughter of my mother-in-law" can mean wife, yes, but it could also be his sister-in-law, if he is married to one of her brothers. So then the female on the bench would be the daughter-in-law of his sister-in-law, making her his niece-in-law-in-law (and if you know enough genealogy to come up with a better name than that minor disaster, please don't hesitate to post!)

Comment: This is why I added the language tag to it.  "the daughter" implies that there is only one, whereas "a daughter" would imply that there is more than one.  That's my justification anyways.  I initially was going to make your answer, and then I decided to write a comment, and then I just updated the tag.  Take my +1 :)

Comment: @LeppyR64 I was aware of the "the"- it's only a restriction if you assume men can only marry women. If John marries Bob, and Bob has a single sister named Sarah, then Sarah would be the daughter of John's mother-in-law

Comment: My comprehension needs some work. :)

Comment: You would need only one "-in-law", as your spouse's niece/nephew is also your own niece/nephew (you don't call the people who marry your aunt/uncle your aunt-/uncle-in-law, do you?).

Comment: @feelinferrety Yeah, but this isn't the guy's spouse's niece-in-law, it's the guy's sister-in-law's niece-in-law

Comment: Rather than try and justify this with text only, I will post my own answer with trees.

Comment: @LeppyR64: u've got it right :)

Comment: @feelinferrety Ah, yup, you're right. Pardon my stubbornness

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer...

> The male would call this female his daughter-in-law.  The female's mother-in-law would be his mother-in-law's daughter (wife).
>
>  [image: Daughter-in-law]

An alternative answer...

> The male would call this female his niece(-in-law). The female's mother-in-law's mother could also have another child to whom the male is married.  The female's mother-in-law's child would be his spouse's niece/nephew, and hence his own niece/nephew. Technically, this person's spouse would be his niece-in-law, but colloquially, he would probably call her his niece.
>
>  [image: Niece(-in-law)]